# Functional data-structures, OO notions of dispatched equality and comparison, StructuralEquality, and referential transparency

Tags: oop, f#, functional-programming, comparison, equality

I have a very CPU intensive F# program that depends on persistent data-structures - about 40% of the total CPU time is spent in the Map module. So I thought I'd try out the PersistentHashMap in FSharpX collections. (BTW, this is already a big improvement over the previous version of F# in VS2013 where the same program spent 70% of its time in Map. I also notice that running programs with the debugger attached doesn't have the huge penalty it did before - good work guys...) There is also a hot-spot where I'm re-sorting all the time, where instead I should be adding to a Heap, so I thought I'd give that a go as well. 
Two issue became immediately apparent:

(1) Swapping out one for the other from an interface perspective proved harder than it seems it should - I.e., making a shim that let me switch from a Map to a PersistentMap, preserving both the needed module-based let-bound functions and Types necessary to use the each map. I know that having full HM type-inference (and no type-classes) is orthogonal to LSP-style referential transparency for the most part - but maybe I was missing some way to do this better with a minimal amount of code.

(2) The biggest problem (which I'd like to focus on here) is the reliance of the F# functional data-structs on oo-style dispatched equality and comparison via the IComparison (when 't : comparison), etc., family of interfaces.

Even for OO programs ISTM that the idea of dispatching equality and comparison is a bad idea -- an object "knows" how to perform its own domain-specific tasks, but it doesn't "know" for the most part what notion of equality is going to be necessary at various points in the program for various purposes -- so equality/comparison should not be part of the object's interface, but when these concepts are needed, they should always be mentioned explicitly. For example, there should never be a .Sort(), only a .SortWith(...). One could argue that even something as basic as structural equality in F# could be explicit a.StructEq(b) or a ~= b - otherwise you always get object.Equals -- but even stipulating that doing things this way is the best for a multi-paradigm language that's a first-class .Net citizen, it seems like there should at least be the option of using passed-in comparison and equality functions, but this is not the case.

This means that: (a) type constraints are enforced even if you don't want them, causing ripples of broken inferred typing (and hundreds of wavy red lines with it being unclear where the actual "problem" is) and (b), that by implementing a notion of equality or comparison that makes one container type happy in one part of your program (and in my case I want to use the same container and item type with two different notions of ordering in two different places), it is likely to silently break (or cause inefficiency, if one subsumes the other) in other parts of the code that depended on the default/previous implementation.

The only way around this that I could think of is wrapping each item a adapter object using new...with object expression - but I really don't want to create so much garbage just to get the code to work.

So, ISTM that we could have a "pure" version of each persistent data struct that could be loaded if desired (even basics like List, etc.) that do not depend on dispatched equality/comparison/hashing and do not impose type constraints - all such needs should be via a passed in fn's at the time of the call. (Dispatched eq/cmp would be only for used for interop with BCL collections that don't accept delegates.) Then we could have a [EqCmpHashThrowNotImplemented] attribute, and I could be sure that there were no default operations happening at all, and I would feel better about the efficiency and predictability of my code. (And this also let's one change from a Record to a Class or visa-versa w/o worrying about any changes in behavior due to default implementations.) Again, this would be *optional*, but done by with a simple import. (Which does mean that each base core collection type would have to be broken out into its own module, which isn't really a bad idea anyway.)

If I've overlooked a better way to do things or there are some patterns people are using here, I'd be interested.

Comment: Pick part of this and phrase it as a question.

Comment: Seeking something `better` is subjective. StackOverflow is about specific objective questions and answers. As such I voted to close as `too broad`. My personal advise is that if you have state in your problem and you don't like what you have to do with F# to get it to work then consider using a different language, or at least parts of it in a different language.

Comment: I require persist. DSs and little "state" which is why I'm using the family of DSs I'm using. The tenant is: having the persistent data-structs use dispatched equality and comparison as the only choice is not scalable, makes one jump though unnecessary hoops, and leads to error-prone and/or inefficient code. 

There are similar questions on SO about wrangling dispatched comparison/equality into the functional coral, but the "specific" answers, although they do the job, underscore the need for a more general approach. If the discussion is "too broad" and needs to move elsewhere, that's fine.